# Why do I get an attribute error with my class?

Tags: python

***EDIT BELOW!***

Here is my retail_item class:

```
#RetailItem Class

class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self, desc, inventory, price):
        self.__desc=desc
        self.__inventory=inventory
        self.__price=price

#mutators
    def set_desc (self, desc):
         self.__desc=desc
    def set_inventory (self, inventory):
         self.__inventory=inventory
    def set_price (self, price):
         self.__price = price

#accessors
    def get_desc(self):
        return self.__desc
    def get_inventory(self):
        return self.__inventory
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Item Description:' + self.__desc, \
               '\tNumber of Units:' + self.__inventory, \
               '\tPrice: $' + self.__price
```

And my cash_register class:

```
#CashRegister Class

class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self, purchase, total, show, clear):
        self.__purchase=purchase
        self.__total=total
        self.__show=show
        self.__clear=clear

#mutators
    def purchase_item(self, purchase):
        self.__purchase=purchase
    def get_total(self, total):
        self.__total=total
    def show_item(self, show):
        self.__show=show
    def clear(self, clear):
        self.__clear=clear

#accessors
    def acc_purchase(self):
        return self.__purchase
    def acc_total(self):
        return self.__total
    def acc_show(self):
        return self.__show
    def acc_clear(self):
        return self.__clear
```

And finally my program:

```
import retail_item
import cash_register

SHOW = 1
PURCHASE = 2
CART = 3
TOTAL = 4
EMPTY = 5
QUIT = 6

def main():
    mylist = make_list()
    #mycr = cash_register.CashRegister(mylist)

    choice = 0

    # Process menu selections until user quits program.
    while choice != QUIT:
        # Get the user's menu choice.
        choice = get_menu_choice()
        # Proces the choice.
        if choice == SHOW:
            show_items(mylist)
        elif choice == PURCHASE:
            purchase_item(mylist)
        elif choice == TOTAL:
            get_total(mylist)
        elif choice == EMPTY:
            clear(mylist)

def make_list():
    item_list = {}

    desc = 'Jacket'
    inventory = 12
    price = 59.95
    entry = retail_item.RetailItem(desc, inventory, price)
    item_list[desc]=entry

    desc = 'Jeans'
    inventory = 40
    price = 34.95
    entry = retail_item.RetailItem(desc, inventory, price)
    item_list[desc]=entry

    desc = 'Shirt'
    inventory = 20
    price = 24.95
    entry = retail_item.RetailItem(desc, inventory, price)
    item_list[desc]=entry

    return item_list

# The get_menu_choice function displays the menu and gets
#   a validated choice from the user.
def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print('CASH REGISTER MENU')
    print('-------------------------')
    print('1. Show Retial Items')
    print('2. Purchase Item(s)')
    print('3. Show Current Shopping Cart')
    print('4. Show Total of Items Purchased')
    print('5. Empty Your Shopping Cart')
    print('6. Quit the program')
    print()

    # Get the user's choice.
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    # Validate the choice.
    while choice < SHOW or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid choice: '))

    # Return the user's choice.
    return choice

def show_items(mylist):
    print('\t\tDescription\t\tUnits in Inventory\t\tPrice')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    x=1
    for item in mylist:
        print('Item #', x, '\t\t', item.get_desc(), '\t\t\t\t', item.get_inventory(), '\t\t\t$', format(item.get_price(), ',.2f'),sep='')
        print()
        x+=1

def purchase_item(mylist):
    desc = input('Enter the item you wish to purchase: ')
    if desc in mylist:
        amount=int(input('How many would you like to buy: '))
        if mylist[units]>0:
            mylist[units]-=amount
        elif (units-amount<0):
            mylist[units]=0
        else:
            mylist[units] = 0

    entry=cash_register.CashRegister(desc, units,)
    mylist[desc]=entry
    print()


def get_total(mylist):
    print()

def clear(mylist):
    print(mylist)
    mylist.clear()
    print(mylist)
main()
```

So my question is, how to I update only one object of a class?
And how do I call on the cash_register class?

Here are the instructions for the assignment, if that helps:

This exercise assumes that you have created the RetailItem class for Programming
Exercise 5. Create a CashRegister class that can be used with the RetailItem class. The
CashRegister class should be able to internally keep a list of RetailItem objects. The
class should have the following methods:
• A method named purchase_item that accepts a RetailItem object as an argument.
Each time the purchase_item method is called, the RetailItem object that is passed as
an argument should be added to the list.
• A method named get_total that returns the total price of all the RetailItem objects
stored in the CashRegister object’s internal list.
• A method named show_items that displays data about the RetailItem objects stored
in the CashRegister object’s internal list.
• A method named clear that should clear the CashRegister object’s internal list.
Demonstrate the CashRegister class in a program that allows the user to select several
items for purchase. When the user is ready to check out, the program should display a list
of all the items he or she has selected for purchase, as well as the total price.

***EDIT:*** Here's my somewhat final code. I know it's not pretty, and I apologize for the lack of comments. I would still like some feedback even though I'll be submitting it shortly (for my own betterment and for job opportunities!) Here it is:

```
import retail_item
import cash_register

SHOW = 1
PURCHASE = 2
TOTAL = 3
EMPTY = 4
QUIT = 5

def main():
    #set all variables to zero
    lister = []
    inv=[]
    cost=[]
    desc=''
    inventory=0
    price=0
    total=0
    purchase=0
    #setting variable for each class
    cash=cash_register.CashRegister(purchase, total, lister, inv, cost)
    retail=retail_item.RetailItem(desc, inventory, price)

    #classes
    desc = 'Jacket'
    inventory = 12
    price = 59.95
    #setting classes
    retail.set_desc(desc)
    retail.set_inventory(inventory)
    retail.set_price(price)
    #Adding to cart
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_desc(), lister)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_inventory(), inv)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_price(), cost)

    desc = 'Jeans'
    inventory = 40
    price = 34.95
    retail.set_desc(desc)
    retail.set_inventory(inventory)
    retail.set_price(price)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_desc(), lister)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_inventory(), inv)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_price(), cost)

    desc = 'Shirt'
    inventory = 20
    price = 24.95
    retail.set_desc(desc)
    retail.set_inventory(inventory)
    retail.set_price(price)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_desc(), lister)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_inventory(), inv)
    cash.purchase_item(retail.get_price(), cost)

    choice = 0

    # Process menu selections until user quits program.
    while choice != QUIT:
        # Get the user's menu choice.
        choice = get_menu_choice()
        # Proces the choice.
        if choice == SHOW:
            show_items(cash, retail, lister, inv, cost)
        elif choice == PURCHASE:
            purchase_item(cash, retail, lister, inv, cost)
        elif choice == TOTAL:
            get_total(cash, retail, lister)
        elif choice == EMPTY:
            price=0
            cash.set_total(price)
            clear(cash, lister)


# The get_menu_choice function displays the menu and gets
#   a validated choice from the user.
def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print('CASH REGISTER MENU')
    print('-------------------------')
    print('1. Show Retail Items')
    print('2. Purchase Item(s)')
    print('3. Show Total of Items Purchased')
    print('4. Empty Your Shopping Cart')
    print('5. Quit the program')
    print()

    # Get the user's choice.
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    # Validate the choice.
    while choice < SHOW or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Please enter a valid choice: '))

    # Return the user's choice.
    return choice

def show_items(cash, retail, lister, inv, cost):
    print('\t\tDescription\t\tUnits in Inventory\t\tPrice')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    cash.show_item(lister, inv, cost)


def purchase_item(cash, retail, lister, inv, cost):

    JACKET=1
    JEANS=2
    SHIRT=3
    QUIT=4
    choice=0

    print()
    print('WHICH WOULD YOU LIKE TO BUY')
    print('-------------------------')
    print('1. Jacket')
    print('2. Jeans')
    print('3. Shirt')
    print('4. Quit')
    print()

    print('Choose as many as you like. Press 4 then ENTER to quit.')
    while choice != QUIT:
        # Get the user's menu choice.
        choice = int(input('Which would you like to buy: '))
        if choice < JACKET or choice > QUIT:
            choice = int(input('Please enter a valid choice: '))

        while choice != QUIT:
            # Proces the choice.
            if choice == JACKET:
                desc = 'Jacket'
                inventory = 12
                price = 59.95
                retail.set_desc(desc)
                retail.set_inventory(inventory)
                retail.set_price(price)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_desc(), lister)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_inventory(), inv)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_price(), cost)
                cash.set_total(price)
                break
            elif choice == JEANS:
                desc = 'Jeans'
                inventory = 40
                price = 34.95
                retail.set_desc(desc)
                retail.set_inventory(inventory)
                retail.set_price(price)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_desc(), lister)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_inventory(), inv)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_price(), cost)
                cash.set_total(price)
                break
            elif choice == SHIRT:
                desc = 'Shirt'
                inventory = 20
                price = 24.95
                retail.set_desc(desc)
                retail.set_inventory(inventory)
                retail.set_price(price)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_desc(), lister)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_inventory(), inv)
                cash.purchase_item(retail.get_price(), cost)
                cash.set_total(price)
                break

    print()


def get_total(cash, retail, lister):    
    print()
    cash.show_items(cash.get_list(lister))
    print('Your total is: $', format(cash.cost_total(),',.2f'))

def clear(cash, lister):
    print('Shopping cart emptied.')
    lister=lister.clear()
    price=0
    cash.set_total(price)

    return lister
main()
```

RetailItem Class:

```
class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self, desc, inventory, price):
        self.__desc=desc
        self.__inventory=inventory
        self.__price=price

#mutators
    def set_desc (self, desc):
        self.__desc=desc
    def set_inventory (self, inventory):
        self.__inventory=inventory
    def set_price (self, price):
        self.__price = price

#accessors
    def get_desc(self):
        return self.__desc
    def get_inventory(self):
        return self.__inventory
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Item Description:' + self.__desc, \
              '\tNumber of Units:' + self.__inventory, \
              '\tPrice: $' + self.__price
```

And again, lastly my CashRegister Class:

```
#CashRegister Class

class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self, purchase, total, lister, inv, cost):
        self.__purchase=purchase
        self.__total=total
        self.__lister=[]
        self.__inv=[]
        self.__cost=[]


#mutators
    def purchase_item(self, purchase, lister):
        self.__purchase=purchase
        lister.append(purchase)
        return lister

    def set_total(self, price):
        self.__total+=price


    def show_item(self, lister, inventory, price):
        i=0
        while i<len(lister):
            s=('Item # %i\t%s\t\t\t\t%i\t\t\t%4.2f') % ((i+1),lister[i],inventory[i],price[i])
            s = s.strip(' \t\n\r')
            print(s)
            i+=1

    def show_items(self, lister):
        i=0
        print('You have purchased the following items')
        while i<len(lister):
            print(lister[i])
            i+=1

    def clear(self, lister):
        i=0
        while i<len(lister):
            del lister[i]
            i+=1
            return lister

    def get_list(self, lister):
        return lister
#accessors
    def acc_purchase(self):
        return self.__purchase
    def cost_total(self):
        return self.__total
    def acc_show(self):
        return self.__show
    def acc_clear(self):
        return self.__clear
```

Thanks again guys! I used this site often, and though I didn't use much of what y'all gave me this time, you're still awesome!

Comment: Please post the stacktrace so we know where to look.

Comment: You refer to class retail_item, yet in the code its `RetailItem`, is this intentional?

Comment: @larsmans I honestly have no idea what stacktrace is. I'm only in a beginner's class...

Comment: @Stedy, the file is named retail_item, the Class is RetailItem. Should've made that more clear I guess.

Comment: @Blake: a Python program that crashes with an exception such as `AttributeError` prints a very detailed error message. When asking why a program crashes, you should post that entire message so that we can tell you how to interpret that, and fix problems yourself in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has a couple of major problems.  Without a stack trace I can't say exactly why you're getting an AttributeError, but I can tell that CashRegister objects can't be instantiated as written.  Its `__init__` refers to nonexistent variables - item and items.

Your CashRegister class is taking arguments to `__init__` that aren't necessary - and in some cases should be methods.  I don't see any reason your CashRegister class should take any `__init__` arguments - it should initialize the list of RetailItem objects and probably a running total and do nothing else.  purchase_item should update those internal attributes, get_total and show_items should read them (or get_total should calculate the total based on the list if you don't keep a running total) and clear should reset them both.

Stylistically, mutators and accessors and hidden internal data are not a Pythonic idiom.  In general Python classes get and set member data directly, and get refactored to use properties if the behavior ever needs to change.  I see that this is for a class/exercise, so you might be using them because they're required, but if not you're better off without them.

*edit*

This is what my main() would look like, making the minimal edits to show the logic:

```
def main():
    items = make_list()
    mycr = cash_register.CashRegister()
    # at this point, mycr.show_items() should return [] and mycr.get_total() should return 0
    choice = 0
    while choice != QUIT:
        choice = get_menu_choice()
        if choice == SHOW:
            mycr.show_items()
        elif choice == PURCHASE:
            item, quantity = get_purchase(items)
            if item and quantity:
                item.set_inventory(max(0, item.get_inventory() - quantity))
                mycr.purchase_item(item, quantity)
        elif choice == TOTAL:
            print(mycr.get_total())
        elif choice == EMPTY:
            mycr.clear()

def get_purchase(items):
    desc = input('Enter the item you wish to purchase: ')
    if desc in items:        
        amount=int(input('How many would you like to buy: '))
        return items[desc], amount
    else:
        return None, 0
```

This doesn't cover every possibility - for instance, as with your original code it allows entering higher quantities than are currently available with no side effect besides setting the quantity to 0.  But the exercise description doesn't mention inventory tracking, so maybe that's not a requirement.

Comment: I've edited my CashRegister class to what it was supposed to be. I just hadn't changed some names yet. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm brand new to Python. We learned we 'have' to have `__init__` in our classes. Would I just add an incrementing loop to the purchase_item? Like this:
    `desc = input('Enter the item you wish to purchase: ')
    if desc in mylist:
        amount=int(input('How many would you like to buy: '))
        if mylist[units]>0:
            mylist[units]-=amount
        elif (units-amount<0):
            mylist[units]=0
        else:
            mylist[units] = 0`

Comment: +1 for the mutators/accessors comment. `__propertyname` is *rarely* used or needed. It's only purpose is when a base class needs to hold on to a reference to a method or property that *it* defines that might be overridden by a subclass. (That's why it does name mangling to include the defining class name.) It does *not* mean "more private than one underscore"!

Comment: `__init__` is not necessarily required for all classes, but it's necessary for your cash register because you'll want to set initial empty values for the items list and running total.  I'll edit some of how I would approach this into my answer - since it's an exercise I don't want to just write the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you @PeterDeGlopper. I ended up writing more of it throughout the day. I'll update with what I have. I'm going to submit it since I'm so close. I know I put way more work into this than what was really needed. I'll update my original post with the updated code.